# Trouble using Runge-Kutta 2nd-order shooting method in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, differential-equations, runge-kutta

I'm having some issues getting my RK2 algorithm to work for a certain second-order linear differential equation. I have posted my current code (with the provided parameters) below. For some reason, the value of y1 deviates from the true value by a wider margin each iteration. Any input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Code:

```
    f = @(x,y1,y2)  [y2; (1+y2)/x];
    a = 1;
    b = 2;
    alpha = 0;
    beta = 1;
   n = 21;
   h = (b-a)/(n-1);
   yexact = @(x) 2*log(x)/log(2) - x +1;
   ye = yexact((a:h:b)');
   s = (beta - alpha)/(b - a);
   y0 = [alpha;s];
   [y1, y2] = RungeKuttaTwo2D(f, a, b, h, y0);
   error = abs(ye - y1);

   function [y1, y2] = RungeKuttaTwo2D(f, a, b, h, y0)
           n = floor((b-a)/h);  

           y1 = zeros(n+1,1); y2 = y1;
           y1(1) = y0(1); y2(1) = y0(2);

           for i=1:n-1
                   ti = a+(i-1)*h;
                   fvalue1 = f(ti,y1(i),y2(i));
                   k1 = h*fvalue1;

                   fvalue2 = f(ti+h/2,y1(i)+k1(1)/2,y2(i)+k1(2)/2);
                   k2 = h*fvalue2;

                   y1(i+1) = y1(i) + k2(1);
                   y2(i+1) = y2(i) + k2(2);
           end
    end
```

Comment: Could you quickly test that in the RK2 function the array `y2` is indeed different from `y1`, that the construction is a copy, not a reference to the same array?

Comment: Why did you decide on a hybrid approach in the ODE function, the value as array, the argument as separate values? Setting `f = @(x,y)  [y(2); (1+y(2))/x];` would also simplify the integration method.

Answer (score 0):

Your exact solution is wrong. It is possible that your differential equation is missing a minus sign.

**`y2'=(1+y2)/x`** has as its solution `y2(x)=C*x-1` and as `y1'=y2` then `y1(x)=0.5*C*x^2-x+D`.

If the sign in the `y2` equation were flipped, **`y2'=-(1+y2)/x`**, one would get `y2(x)=C/x-1` with integral `y1(x)=C*log(x)-x+D`, which contains the given exact solution.

```
0=y1(1) = -1+D  ==>  D=1
1=y1(2) = C*log(2)-1  ==  C=1/log(2)
```

---

Additionally, the arrays in the integration loop have length `n+1`, so that the loop has to be from `i=1` to `n`. Else the last element remains zero, which gives wrong residuals for the second boundary condition.

Correcting that and enlarging the computation to one secant step finds the correct solution for the discretization, as the ODE is linear. The error to the exact solution is bounded by `0.000285`, which is reasonable for a second order method with step size `0.05`.